# WPF WindowChrome Fill / Foreground Color

Tags: wpf, window-chrome

I am currently trying to keep all the Windows 11 features like the docking preview while still customizing a windows title bar.
I figured that using WindowChrome is my best bet(?)

```
<WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <WindowChrome ResizeBorderThickness="3"
                  GlassFrameThickness="30" />
</WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
```

But that unfortunately gets rid of the foreground color of the title bar.
I mean - the buttons are still there, but the window title & control button icons are transparent.

Is this the wrong approach? Would there be an easy solution for this? I would like to avoid making a completely custom title bar because of mentioned reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the future people with a similar question:
@AZ Software could provide me the necessary docs I was looking for:

- Docking feature implementation for custom TitleBar:
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/apply-snap-layout-menu
- Rounded corners implementation
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/apply-rounded-corners

Answer (score 1):

Instead of recreating the window from scratch, have you looked into WPF libraries like [MahApps](https://mahapps.com/) or  [ModernWPF](https://github.com/Kinnara/ModernWpf) which include custom windows and titlebars. For example in ModernWPF, you can change the background and foreground of the titlebar.

Comment: Yes I have, but as mentioned in the question - I want to KEEP the windows 11 features, and as far as I am a ware, that is only really possible by keeping the default windows title bar.

Comment: You can use the native WinAPI's to add the windows 11 features, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/apply-snap-layout-menu https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/apply-rounded-corners

Comment: Now that is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Hey I would recommend for you to change the title to 'Windows 11 titlebar features'.